# Can I sync many google accounts into one Stack exchange account?

Tags: email, sync, user-accounts

I'm now using several mail accounts for quite different purposes. I'm trying to sync 2 of my google accounts into 1 Stack overflow account. I registered with the first one (first@email.com) and then change my profile email to the second(second@email.com). But as far as I know it doesn't do anything much on my account setting or syncing my badge, reputation ..etc....

Today I'm log in using the second@email.com (which is not originally registered for the site. Stack overflow asked me if I want to create a new account, I clicked yes and it turns out to be really ridiculous. Now I cannot save my first@email.com Stack account which has email field filled with second@email.com email address (it work earlier) or delete the new account I just have created.

Anything could I do to fix the problem, please help me out. Thank you very much!

Comment: You cannot merge multiple Google Accounts into a single Stack Exchange profile.  Each google account can only be attached to a single Stack Exchange profile.

Comment: That really sucks!

Comment: @DuyTran was there a reason you wished to do so?